# Perda do foco no Entry no Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Estou construindo uma aplicação mobile com o Xamarin Forms e C# onde necessito fazer a checagem do CPF e a validação do e-mail. 
Estou querendo fazer as validações assim que o campo perde o foco. Estou usando em minha aplicação o MVVM.

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver o problema?

Comment: Desta forma sua pergunta fica muito ampla, tente postar o trecho o quão você teve dificuldade.

Answer (score -2):

Como o @WictorChaves falou, sua pergunta está muito ampla. Mas, amplamente falando também, você pode gerenciar o evento `Unfocused` do componente `Entry`.

Veja um exemplo:

**Declarando  via XAML**

```
<Entry Text={Binding CampoTexto} Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused"/>
```

**Ou declarando via C#**

```
Entry entry = new Entry();
entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("CampoTexto"));
entry.Unfocused += Entry_Unfocused;
```

**E a implementação do manipulador de eventos ficaria assim:**

```
private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    // Seu tratamento seria feito aqui
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Diego, ajudou sim. O manipulador de eventos (Entry_Unfocused) deve ficar no code behind? Tem como transferi-lo para a View Model?

Comment: Sim, manipulador de eventos ficaria no codebehind da página. Transferir não. Você pode a partir do manipulador de eventos, invocar um método ou comando da viewmodel... é difícil dizer sem ver o cenário no qual você está trabalhando...

Comment: Por exemplo, você disse na pergunta que está usando MVVM, mas quer dar tratativas baseado em eventos de tela (como é o caso do unfocused), e isso não faz muito sentido. Em MVVM você deveria estar preocupado com mudanças de estado das propriedades da viewmodel em vez de eventos de foco da tela, entende?